# Web-mapping a PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, web-mapping

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS spatial relational database for my university project with objects, their coordinates and attributes (1:n, n:m relations).
I would like to map my spatial objects online and run queries, however, I am not ready yet to set up a web server and write server side scripts.

Are there any web mapping platforms that will allow me for now to visualize the data from the exported database? I suppose in this case I have to merge all of the related tables with attributes into one file.